# Why can't I copy from nano to clipboard?

Tags: copy-paste, clipboard, nano, copy, terminator

Why does `nano` not support simple `Ctrl + C` into clipboard? I'm using it with `gnome-terminator` on Linux Mint and just want to copy a few lines from my `.bashrc` into a text editor. When I mark a text passage, right-clicking on it doesn't work, I need to *"double-right-click"* on it in order to open a context menu, but there "copy" is grayed out. `Ctrl + Shift + C` *also* doesn't work. I already checked "Copy on selection" in the Terminator preferences - but it doesn't work either. This is killing me...it's such a simple functionality.

How can I enable *copy & paste*? Is there a straightforward way or do I have to change the text editor altogether?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terminator doesn't know anything about which text you have marked within nano. In general, the terminal only understands the formatting, but not the meaning, of what it's told to display – when you mark something in nano, it just tells the terminal to show that text in different color. (Similarly, the terminal only knows text that is *visible*, but not the text that's scrolled away in nano.)

On the other hand, nano doesn't know anything about clipboards. (The clipboard is a feature of X11, the graphics system, so purely-terminal apps cannot access it as easily.) Support for the X11 clipboard *could* have been added to nano, like it was added to Vim for the `"+` register, but they probably chose not to.

So with nano, the only straightforward way is to select text *on the terminal* using Shift+mouse or Ctrl+Shift+mouse, after which it'll become copyable using Terminator's Ctrl+Shift+C. (Unfortunately this can only copy as much text as fits on one screen.)

Or you could just directly open your ~/.bashrc *in* whatever text editor you want.

Comment: *"So with nano, the only straightforward way is to select text on the terminal using Shift+mouse or Ctrl+Shift+mouse, after which it'll become copyable using Terminator's Ctrl+Shift+C."* - Perfect, this works! *"Or you could just directly open your ~/.bashrc in whatever text editor you want."* - Sometimes one doesn't see the wood for the trees